# Issue when debug and publish an extension created with SharePoint Framework Version 1.7 on a SharePoint Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sharepoint-framework, gulp

I create an extension with SharePoint Framework 1.7 with yo @microsoft/sharepoint by selecting the options as indicated below:

- SharePoint 2019 onwards, including SharePoint Online.
- Use the current folfer
- Do you want to allow the tenatn admin ...? Yes
- Extension
- Application Customizer

I update the parameters in the **server.json** file. I create certificate and execute node with the commands: `gulp trust-dev-cert AND gulp serve`.
The message to load the debug scripts is activated in the browser and when the browser debugging tool is executed the Placeholders Top and Bottom are not activated.
When I generate the package with the *.sppkg* extension and upload it to the site the application catalog and I want to activate it in the SharePoint site collection, the error page with the correlation identifier is presented and upon consulting this error it indicates that the following:

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx, Error=The
>   system account can not perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

Double check what version of the framework is being targeted.  By default it points to 1.4.1 … we changed it internally to 1.4.0 and the extensions started working (none of them worked at all until that change!)  Let us know if that helps for you.

Ralph in Chicago